# Clarifying the Existence and Uniqueness of Solutions to an Initial Value Problem Given Local Lipschitz Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

For an open interval $I$ and an open region $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ let $F: I \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n},( t, x) \mapsto F(t, x)$, continuous and locally Lipschitz continuous with respect to $x$.

For each $\left(t_{0}, x_{0}\right) \in I \times \Omega $ then there is [...] one solution $\varphi: I \rightarrow \mathbb {R}^{n} $ of
Initial value problem $\varphi^{\prime}(t)=F(t, \varphi(t)) $ with $\varphi\left(t_{0}\right)=x_{0} $.

Here [...] should be replaced with: exactly, at least, at most

I was sure it has to be "exactly", because of lipschitz, but it says it's false because: "Only uniqueness follows from local Lipschitz, but not global existence."

Now I think that it's " at least" one solution because of local lipschitz continuity and Peano theorem

An example would help a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the interval $I$.

If $F$ is as in the assumptions, solutions exist and are unique on small open intervals about $t_0$. But they may not exist on the entire interval. Therefore *at most* is correct.

Example: Consider $x'= x^2, x(0)  = x_0 = 1$. The unique solution is $x(t) = (1-t)^{-1}$. It exists on the set$(-\infty,1)$. But on the interval $(-2,2)$ this solution does not exist.

Comment: The soultion is $x(t)=1/(1-t)$.

Comment: The question by the OP is very interesting to me because there is no continuity condition on time variable. Could you please have a look at my strongly related question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453806/references-for-derivative-w-r-t-initial-condition-of-an-ode)?

Comment: @Akira : the rhs function is continuous as function in 2 variables, which is the usual assumption in the standard existence theorems.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ah my bad. Anyway, I am very grateful if you can elaborate on my mentioned question...

Comment: I still see the wrong solution $x(t)=(1-t)$.